# Creating Z-Score grouped by column value in R

Tags: r, normalization

I was wondering if there was an easy way in R to create a Z-score column grouped by a column value.

For example, turning a dataframe like this

```
  Obs      Year          Dollars
   1       1960            2
   2       1960            3
   3       1960            5
   4       1960            6
   5       1961           15
   6       1961           20 
   7       1961           25
   8       1961           40
```

into something like this

```
  Obs      Year          Dollars     Z-Score
   1       1960            2         -1.265
   2       1960            3         -0.633
   3       1960            5          0.633
   4       1960            6          1.266
   5       1961           15         -1.069
   6       1961           20         -0.535
   7       1961           25          0
   8       1961           40          1.604
```

Where the samples are separated by year

Comment: Is this your full data? I'm getting completely different z-scores.

Comment: @RuiBarradas this is just a random example. I calculated the z-scores by hand, so it could be wrong. But I found the average/SD for both the 1960 (4, 1.58) and 1961 (25, 9.35) and just calculated it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`it's very simple, just use `ave`.

```
dat$Z.Score <- ave(dat$Dollars, dat$Year, FUN = scale)
dat
#  Obs Year Dollars    Z.Score
#1   1 1960       2 -1.0954451
#2   2 1960       3 -0.5477226
#3   3 1960       5  0.5477226
#4   4 1960       6  1.0954451
#5   5 1961      15 -0.9258201
#6   6 1961      20 -0.4629100
#7   7 1961      25  0.0000000
#8   8 1961      40  1.3887301
```

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Obs = 1:8, Year = c(1960L, 1960L, 1960L, 1960L, 
1961L, 1961L, 1961L, 1961L), Dollars = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 
20L, 25L, 40L)), .Names = c("Obs", "Year", "Dollars"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

**EDIT.**
Following the discussion with akrun in the comments, I will post his solution using package `data.table`. The result is the same, only the class of the result is different, `dat` becomes an object of class `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[, Z.Score := scale(Dollars), Year]
```

Comment: Or with `data.table` `setDT(dat)[, Z.Score := scale(Dollars), Year]`

Comment: @akrun I believe you should add that comment as an answer.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  It's okay.  It is only similar to your answer

Comment: @akrun The general principle is the same but `data.table` makes it different.

Comment: It's okay, I think you could edit it in your answer because the skeleton is the same