# Calculate sub-column-wise z scores in R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, multiple-columns

I have the following example `data.frame`.

```
df = data.frame(a=c(rep("a",8), rep("b",5), rep("c",7), rep("d",10)), 
    b=rnorm(30, 6, 2), 
    c=rnorm(30, 12, 3.5), 
    d=rnorm(30, 8, 3)
    )
```

For each column, I would like to calculate z scores per subgroup defined in column a. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977761/creating-z-score-grouped-by-column-value-in-r) was helpful for me and I can now do this using the following:

```
 df$b.zscore <- ave(df$b, df$a, FUN = scale)
 df$c.zscore <- ave(df$c, df$a, FUN = scale)
 df$d.zscore <- ave(df$d, df$a, FUN = scale)
```

But my real data has many more columns. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this for columns b-d? Maybe using a `for` loop? How could I do that, please? I hope anyone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` over the columns :

```
cols <- c('b', 'c', 'd')
new_cols <- paste0(cols, '_zscore')
df[new_cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) ave(x, df$a, FUN = scale))
```

---

However, such operations which operate on multiple columns are better done with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(across(b:d, list(zscore = ~as.numeric(scale(.)))))
  #For dplyr < 1.0.0
  #mutate_at(vars(b:d), list(zscore = ~as.numeric(scale(.))))
```

and with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, (new_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(scale(x))), a, 
            .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: This is great. Is it also possible to add them as columns to the original table, as per post above? That would be terrific.

Comment: Which answer are you using?  `base R`,  `dplyr` or `data.table` ?

Comment: Does not matter, you choose your favourite :)